# Is there a way to 'interpoloate' a column's value as the comparison operator in the WHERE clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, string-interpolation, comparison-operators

Let's say I have a column named "comparison_operator" with values like '>', '=', '<'. in the "products" table. Is there a way to use it in the WHERE clause like the following?

```
SELECT products.name FROM products WHERE products.price #{comparison_operator} products.cost
```

I believe the answer to this question is no but would like to see if there's alternative way to achieve the same purpose. Thank you!

Comment: does MySql have an "eval" function?

Comment: More or less a Yes @theGleep MySQL has PREPARE/EXECUTE clauses to allow dynamic SQL execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not like that.

```
CASE
  WHEN products.comparison_operator = ">"
    THEN products.price > products.cost
  WHEN products.comparison_operator = "<"
    THEN products.price < products.cost
  ELSE
    products.price = products.cost
END
```

Comment: Yes I thought about comparing the comparison_operator on a case by case basis too but it seems quite cumbersome. I guess there's no way to do it more dynamically?

Comment: You could write a UDF to put it all in one place instead of writing it out everywhere.